# Check whether a column returns a set of values in sql

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have a table having a column which contain multiple occurrence of numeric values 1,2 and 3 only.

```
SELECT * from table1 where column_name=1

SELECT * from table1 where column_name=2

SELECT * from table1 where column_name=3
```

Is it possible that I can make these queries to a single query because calling 3 sql select query statement for a single requirement from a single table look awkward .
I need to do something if the table has atleast single row for each condition.
I have used the following query:

```
SELECT * 
from table1 
where column_name IN (1,2,3).
```

It return the data even if column with any of the value doesn't exist in the table.I need to return the table if the table has at least one row for each where clause.

I have also tried the following query:

```
SELECT *     
FROM table1 
where (column_name =1 
AND column_name =2 AND column_name =3)
//this returns null even if a single column has value 1,2 and 3
```

Comment: "*even if a single column has value 1, 2 and 3*"  - a single column can **not** have all three values at the same time. Remember that the condition in the where clause is a applied for the columns of *one* single row.

Comment: I know that.I have modified the requirement.Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN column_name = 1 THEN 1 END) +
       MAX(CASE WHEN column_name = 2 THEN 1 END) +
       MAX(CASE WHEN column_name = 3 THEN 1 END)
FROM table1
```

to check if the specified condition is satisified.

The above will return `3` if **all three** values `(1,2,3)` are contained in `column_name` column of `table1` (in separate records of course), and `NULL` otherwise.

You can now use the above query in a `CTE` like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN column_name = 1 THEN 1  END) +
          MAX(CASE WHEN column_name = 2 THEN 1  END) +
          MAX(CASE WHEN column_name = 3 THEN 1  END) AS cnt
   FROM table1
)
SELECT t.*
FROM #table1 AS t
CROSS JOIN CTE 
WHERE cnt = 3
```

to return the table, if the table satisfies the requirement, i.e. if the table contains:

- *at least one* row with `column_name = 1` **and**
- *at least one* row with `column_name = 2` **and**
- *at least one* row with `column_name = 3`

Comment: When I check the code,its showing syntax errors near (

Comment: @Techy I have re-written my answer. Please check if it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: Wouldn't that be faster SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM Table1

Comment: The OP want to check against *specific* values, i.e. `1,2 and 3`, not *any* three different values. Well, at least this is what I have understood from his question.

Comment: " which contain multiple occurrence of numeric values 1,2 and 3 only" here is the "only" word which make me thing that the table will always contain only those values

Comment: @mcl The column will only contain any of the values(1,2,3)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying if the column will ever contain only those 3 values SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM Table1  is more efficient and will execute faster. If that statement returns the number 3 that means you have at least one row of every value (1, 2 or 3). If it returns 2 for example that means that the table is missing some distinct value. Anyway good luck with what you're doing :). Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: In case 'column-name' of 'Table1' cannot contain any values other than (1,2,3) then @mcl is correct and offers a cleaner and more efficient solution than mine

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM Table1
```

Later on you check if the result is 3 which means that you have at least one row of each number

Or

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(1) as Cnt FROM Table1 GROUP BY column_name
```

This will give you every different number + it's count (how many times you have that row in the table)

Or

```
  DECLARE @numbers AS TABLE(N INT)
  INSERT INTO @numbers VALUES(1), (2), (3)

  SELECT column_name, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN column_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cnt
  FROM @numbers 
  LEFT JOIN Table1 ON @numbers.N = column_name
  GROUP BY column_name
```

This will give you every number even if it does not exist yet in Table1 (the count is 0)

Answer (score 1):

Your first and second queries are the same, and should return the same result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE column_name IN (1,2,3)
```

This is basically saying: Get me all rows from table1 where column_name is ***1*, *2* OR *3***.

That's the problem with your third query. You're using AND, and this will not return anything in your case since column_name can't be **1, 2 AND 3** at the same time.

If you just want to see if the values exist (one or more), and apply other filters, you can use:

```
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT column_name FROM table1 WHERE (column_name IN (1, 2, 3)))
```